# Bootstrap LESS - Grunt watch output to specific dir

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, less, watch

When it comes to command line, batch and stuff I'm total noob. Honestly.
I'm using Windows 7 64-bit and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt). I wanted to try Bootstrap with LESS for two reasons:

1. Better management of Bootstrap's CSS and color variables
2. To learn LESS so I can use it on my own later.

So I went with instructions and installed node.js and Grunt.

As long as I use only `> grunt dist` command, every goes smooth and clean. No errors, CSS ready to go. But it's kinda boring to run command everytime and moving files (i keep .less project separate from my php framework), so I looked upon `> grunt watch`. It works fine, but I still need to move my files.

And here comes the quesion:
Is there a way to change that command so Grunt will save bootstrap files somewhere else?

The `Gruntfile.js` I use is [vanilla one](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) I got with bootstrap.

Comment: You should edit your Gruntfile.js shipped with the bootstrap source code. But i' not sure, why you should move your files in the first place?

Comment: Because I have whole Bootstrap LESS project in `bootstrap` dir. So my css files are in: `bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`. And I want them in: `css/bootstrap.css`.

Comment: Well indeed you should edit the Gruntfile.less. Find the `less` task with the `compileCore` argument. Than you should edit the `dest` option by changing `dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css` into `../css/<%= pkg.name %>.css` Notice that the `watch` task runs the less task, so you don't have to edit that.

Comment: @BassJobsen Well, thank you! That helped! I had to change path in more places, details are in question's edit

Comment: fine. Do not edit your question with the answer, but post an answer and accept that

Answer (score 3):

**Solution (with help from Bass Jobsen)**
I had to change `Gruntfile.js`. In Notepad++ I did changed (20 occurences) this:

```
'dist/
```

to

```
'../
```

So all my bootstrap files (css, fonts and js) saves now in `css`, `js` and `fonts` directories instead of `bootstrap/dist/css` etc.